# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on localized string with parameter

Tags: ios, swift

Experiencing an odd issue here that only appears on some phones. I have a custom UIView that I init like so.

```
let passQuizToTutorAlert = SAAlertView(title: NSLocalizedString("quiz-title", comment: ""), message: String(format: NSLocalizedString("quiz-message-parameter", comment: ""), 4), textAlignment: .left, customView: headerImageView, alternativeLayout: true)
```

The line above crashes with this error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x4)`

I played with the various methods in the init. It seems that it only crashes if I use a localized string with a parameter. For example the code here has no issues:

```
let passQuizToTutorAlert = SAAlertView(title: NSLocalizedString("quiz-title", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("quiz-message", comment: ""), textAlignment: .left, customView: headerImageView, alternativeLayout: true)
```

The localized string it crashes on is defined like so:

```
"quiz-message-parameter" = "You have %d credits left";
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why does it only crash for a localized string with a parameter?

EDIT:

I did a little debugging. This crash is independent of the alert view. If I try:

```
let aString = String(format: "You have %d credits left", 4)
        print(astring)
```

It doesn't crash. But when it's mixed with localized string it crashes:

```
let aString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("quiz-message-parameter", comment: ""), 3)
```

Comment: First of all: Isolate your problem from unrelated stuff. Does `NSLocalizedString()` return the correct result? Does `String(format: "You have %d credits left", 4)` work? Is this related to SAAlertView at all? *Debug!*

Comment: Independent of the SAAlertView. Only crashes when using NSLocalizedString with String format. @MartinR

Comment: Simulator or device? Which device?

Comment: Device. iPhone6s. iOS 10.2.1. However not sure the phone model is related. On a coworkers iPhone 7 it crashes on mine it doesn't. All iOS version 10.2.1

Comment: Try with `%ld` format instead of `%d`

Comment: When you print it in your first case, what does "aString" contain?

Comment: Are you using different languages? Could it be that on one language, it's not "%d", but "%@" or something else? Could you check `NSLocalizedString("quiz-message-parameter", comment: "")`?

Comment: @Larme it was that! If you post your answer I'll accept. thanks

Comment: Yes, notice that the address was 0x4 in the crash, which matches up with the value passed to `stringWithFormat:`. Nice catch @Larme !

Answer (score 13):

A format with a wrong placeholder for a variable causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

In the case of `NSLocalizedString()`, you may want to check ALL versions of it for ALL the languages available.

It happened not long ago on a project of mine, for all the versions except one, the placeholder was `%d`, and in one it was `%@`, causing crash only when the phone was into the culprit language.